# Matlab for loop vectorization and memory

Tags: matlab, memory, vectorization

X,Y and z are coordinates representing surface. In order to calculate some quantity, lets call it flow, at point i,j of the surface, i need to calculate contibution from all other points (i0,j0). To do so i need for example to know cos of angles between point i0,j0 and all other points (alpha). Then all contirbutions from i0,j0 must be multiplied on some constants and added. zv0 at every point i,j is final needed result.

I came up with some code written below and it seems to be extremely unappropriate. First of all it slows down rest of the program and seems to use all of the available memory. My system has 4gb physical memory and 12gb swap file and it always runs out of memory, though all of variables sizes are not bigger then 10kb. Please help up with speed up/vectorization and memory problems.

```
parfor i0=2:1:length(x00);
  for j0=2:1:length(y00);
    zv=red3dfunc(X0,Y0,f,z0,i0,j0,st,ang,nx,ny,nz);
    zv0=zv0+zv;
  end
end


function[X,Y,z,zv]=red3dfunc(X,Y,f,z,i0,j0,st,ang,Nx,Ny,Nz)
x1=X(i0,j0);
y1=Y(i0,j0);
z1=z(i0,j0);
alpha=zeros(size(X));
betha=zeros(size(X));
r=zeros(size(X));
XXa=X-x1;
YYa=Y-y1;
ZZa=z-z1;
VEC=((XXa).^2+(YYa).^2+(ZZa).^2).^(1/2);
VEC(i0,j0)=VEC(i0-1,j0-1);
XXa=XXa./VEC;
YYa=YYa./VEC;
ZZa=ZZa./VEC;
alpha=-(Nx(i0,j0).*XXa+Ny(i0,j0).*YYa+Nz(i0,j0).*ZZa);
betha=Nx.*XXa+Ny.*YYa+Nz.*ZZb;
r=VEC;
zv=(1/pi)*st^2*ang.*f.*(alpha).*betha./r.^2;
```

Comment: How big are `x00` and `y00`?

Comment: such that X0=meshgrid(x00,y00). If you need numbers they are at least 50

Answer (score 3):

The obvious thing to do this is to use Kroneker product. The matlab function is kron(A,B) for matricies of dimensions nAxmA and nBxmB. This function will return matrix of dimension (nA*nB)x(mA*mB), which will look something like

```
[a11*B a12*B ... a1mA*B;
.......................;
anA1*B ........ anAmA*B]
```

So your problem may be solved by introducing the matrix of ones I=ones(size(X)). You will then define your XXa, YYa, ZZa and VEC matricies without any loop as

```
XXa = kron(I,X)-kron(X,I);
YYa = kron(I,Y)-kron(Y,I);
ZZa = kron(I,Z)-kron(Z,I);
VEC=((XXa).^2+(YYa).^2+(ZZa).^2).^(1/2);
```

You will then find VEC for any i0,j0 as (if you define n and m as size components of X)

```
VEC((1+n*(i0-1)):(n*i0),(1+m*(j0-1)):(m*j0))
```

Comment: solid answer. i'll definitely try it

Comment: i've tried to use this approach, too bad it works even slower then with for loop

Comment: This is a kind of sad. The only thing I can recommend to you is to use repmat(X,size(X)) instead of kron(I,X). Maybe this will improve the speed a little.